# QGIS how to select entries not in another layer

Tags: qgis, expression

I have 2 layers of polygons in QGIS which are *layer1* and *layer2*.
they both have column `id`.

The goal is to select items in layer1 that not appear in layer2 using unique field `id`.

For example:

layer 1 has id: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

layer 2 has id: 1, 2, 3, 4

by using expressions like

```
id not in layer2
```

How can I write the expression to have item 5 in layer 1 selected?

Comment: You could try attribute joining by id then select the ones that have no match https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Comment: Look at the aggregate and array functions. For example `array_agg("id")` should give a list of all id's in the current layer. To check if the current feature's id is in the list of id's in another layer it would be something like: `array_contains( aggregate('layer2','array',"id"), "id")`.  I haven't tested this expression so it may have errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that using an **SQL Query** in the **DB Manager** of QGIS.

You choose Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers you can then try queries like the following :

```
select ID from layer1 where ID not in (select ID from layer2)
```

Depending on the size of your tables it can be a bit time consuming ...

Comment: Let me add: the `NOT IN` construct will return an empty set when either side of the comparison contains a single `NULL` value ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN))! Either add `WHERE ID IS NOT NULL` in the sub-select, or use the (more performant) `WHERE NOT EXISTS` construct.

Answer (score 5):

You could also *filter by expression* using the **Advanced Filter** in the **Attribute Table** (of `layer1`):

```
get_feature_by_id('layer2',$id) IS NULL
```

This will filter out the features of `layer1` whose `$id` is *not* found in `layer2`.

**Note**: $id refers to the current feature's id, as assigned automatically within QGIS. As noted by @Mike D, you may want to use another attribute as identifier, in which case you need to put double-quotes around its name (single-quotes point to an attribute, double-quotes point to its value). For the example below, we could have written the filter expression as follows

```
get_feature_by_id('layer2',"CODE_OBJ") IS NULL
```

[image: Advanced Filter]

Comment: I liked and used this method. For me it was  get_feature_by_id( 'layer2',"OBJECTID") IS NULL

Comment: Indeed, you can use any other object identifier and in that case it should be written with double-quotes around its name. I have added this as an edit to my answer. Thanks!